# Does using lvextend destroy data already on the volume?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Does resizing a logical volume with lvextend and e2resize destroy data already on the volume?

See also this related unanswered question and some examples of the process:
[Can I resize the root partition without uninstalling and reinstalling Linux (or losing data)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28125/22635)

Comment: What's "unanswered" about the related question? What would be the point of e2resize if it destroyed data?

Comment: @Mat: The question explains how to resize, not whether data is preserved or not. I agree that it would be more useful to preserve data but computers being what they are, there may be circumstances in which data is not preserved. Well worth understanding fully if production data is at stake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing logical volumes will not destroy your data. See the following link https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/index.html