# How to increase size on root.union partition

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, raspberry-pi, gparted

I am trying to update 3B image to run on 3B+ but it needs to install packages worth 480MBs. They are to be installed on /var/cache/apt but I only have about 360MBs free on that partition. You can have a better understanding by looking at the image attached [image: Disk partitions]
The sd card has about 3Gigs of unallocated memory that I can use to expand mmcblk0p1 or p2 but I don't know how to expand root.union.

Comment: I think your question is not really clear because it is a single piece of text without paragraphs. Use carriage return to increase legibility. Providing `mount` output may also help

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not `root.union` (`/` mount point) you need to expand but `/deb/mmcblk0p2` partition (`/ro` mount point).

You should be able to resize the underlying FS. The following links may help you:

- [How can I resize my root partition in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57410/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition-in-debian)
- [How can I resize an ext root partition at runtime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime)

As your `/ro` *should be* mounted read-only (I assume this, but can't know for sure since I miss your `mount` command output) I think it could be easy to do.

Comment: I have already expanded mmcblk0p2 from 4Gigs to about 7Gigs but /var still returned me error saying that you need more space. I think /ro and / are two different partitions?